# Applying an operation (whose result depends on the information in the entire DataFrame) on certain rows of the DataFrame in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently struggling with implementing a Spark-y way to do an operation with PySpark. I have a large DataFrame (of ~ 500,000 rows) with the following structure

```
   ID    DATE    CHANGE    POOL
   -----------------------------
 1 ID1   DATE1   CHANGE1   POOL1
 2 ID2   DATE2   CHANGE2   POOL2
 3 ID3   DATE3   CHANGE3   POOL3
 4 ID4   DATE4   CHANGE4   POOL4
 ....
```

where `ID`s are unique, `DATE`s are not necessarily equidistant from each other (and could potentially be repeating), `CHANGE`s could be any number of `float` type (usually, but not always, between, say, -500.0 to +500.0), and `POOL`s can be either an empty list `[]` or a non-empty list of varied length, depending on the specific row. We can safely assume that the DataFrame is sorted by `DATE`.

I want to replace the empty lists in the `POOL` column via the following operation. I am only considering events within a window of `W` days (say, `W` is 180 days).

1. For a row with an empty `POOL`, I note the `DATE` of that row
2. I select *all* the rows from the original DataFrame which fall within a window of `W` days in the past from the date mentioned in step 1.
3. From this subset, I collect the list of all `CHANGE`s (possibly with `collect_list()` function).
4. I assign this list to the `POOL` column corresponding to the row mentioned in step 1.

I tried to (partially) achieve this with window functions as follows (I can safely remove the line with `partitionBy()`)

```
POOL_DAYS = 180
days = lambda i: i * 86400
window_glb = Window\
                 .partitionBy()\
                 .orderBy(col('DATE').cast('long'))\
                 .rangeBetween(-days(POOL_DAYS), 0)
df = df.withColumn('POOL', collect_list('CHANGE').over(window_glb))
```

but it is crashing with this error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1859.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 203.1 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 203.1 (TID 6339, xxxxxxxxxx.com, executor 1):
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

which, to me, looks like a running-out-of-memory issue. To test for this, I used the same operation on a much smaller subset of the original DataFrame, and it finished successfully.

Please note that I do understand that the above implementation repeats the operation for all the rows without considering whether the `POOL` column is empty or not, but I first wanted to see if I can get this to work or not before proceeding with the next step; it seems like this method is not applicable to large DataFrames.

The brute-force (and not Spark-y at all) method is to do a `for`-loop over the rows with empty `POOL` and apply the following regular (not UDF) function on the original DataFrame

```
def get_pool(row, window_size):
    end_date = row.DATE
    start_date = end_date - datetime.timedelta(days = window_size)
    return df.where((col('DATE') < end_date) & (col('DATE') >= start_date))\
             .agg(collect_list('CHANGE'))\
             .rdd.flatMap(list).first()
```

but, expectedly, it takes a very long time to finish.

**UPDATE:** I have also tried using a UDF

```
def get_pool(date, window_size):
    end_date = date
    start_date = end_date - datetime.timedelta(days = window_size)
    return df.where((col('DATE') < end_date) & (col('DATE') >= start_date))\
             .agg(collect_list('CHANGE'))\
             .rdd.collect()
get_pool_udf = udf(get_pool, ArrayType(DoubleType()))
```

but because the outcome of the function depends on the information on the entire (or most of the) DataFrame, it stops with an error

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o1857.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
```

Short of the first method based on window functions, the brute-force method, and the broken UDF try, how can I achieve this? I need to be able to group and process the subset of the DataFrame that falls within a certain date range from the date of interest; how can I do this with Spark?

I am very new to Spark (and PySpark) and am having a hard time to think about this problem. I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question: I select the `ID`s and `DATE`s for which the `POOL` column is empty, and I perform a join of the two DataFrames while restricting to those rows which fall within the date range of interest. Grouping by `ID` and collecting the `CHANGE`s within each group as a list gives the desired list to be assigned to the `POOL` column for the rows whose `POOL` were an empty list:

```
renamed_df = df.select('DATE', 'CHANGE')\
               .withColumnRenamed('DATE', 'r_DATE')\
               .withColumnRenamed('CHANGE', 'r_CHANGE')

no_pool_df = df.where(size('POOL') == 0)

cross_df = no_pool_df\
            .join(renamed_df,\
                    (renamed_df.r_DATE >= date_sub(no_pool_df.DATE, POOL_DAYS)) &\
                    (renamed_df.r_DATE < no_pool_df.DATE)\
                , 'right')\
            .select('ID', 'r_CHANGE')\
            .groupBy('ID')\
            .agg(collect_list('r_CHANGE'))\
            .withColumnRenamed('ID', 'no_pool__ID')\
            .withColumnRenamed('collect_list(r_CHANGE)', 'no_pool__POOL')

df = df.join(cross_df, cross_df.no_pool__ID == df.ID, 'left_outer')\
       .drop('no_pool__ID')
```

Now, the DataFrame `df` has two columns that together contain the required information, the original `POOL` and the newly created `no_pool__POOL`. I use the following UDF to properly mix these two into one column, `POOL_mix`:

```
def mix_pools(history, no_history):
    if not history:
        return no_history
    else:
        return history
mix_pools_udf = sfn.udf(mix_pools, ArrayType(DoubleType()))

df = df.withColumn('POOL_mix', mix_pools_udf(col('POOL'), col('no_pool__POOL')))\
       .drop('POOL', 'no_pool__POOL')
```